# Fixed headers with scrolling using multiple Fullcalendars

Tags: html, css, scroll, fullcalendar

I am extending a scheduling app that displays multiple Fullcalendars in agendaDayView to show the day's schedule for multiple people.  Having each Fullcalendar use its own scrollbar has been rejected; accordingly, all the calendars are displayed full-length, with a single scrollbar set in the surrounding div.

The problem now is to have the headers stay fixed during vertical scrolling.  There are other requirements for extended header functionality (additional data, icons, links, etc.), so it made more sense to me to make my own headers above each Fullcalendar div.

Using CSS and placing the divs correctly, I was able to get the calendars to vertically scroll separately from the headers, thus achieving a 'fixed header' effect.  The problem was then horizontal scrolling:  if I made the divs extend outward horizontally, then the vertical scrollbar for the div containing the calendars was all the way to the right, outside of visibility.

I have also tried plugins for fixed headers by setting using a  with arbitrary text for the headers and then putting the Fullcalendar divs inside  elements in a single row.  These all failed in different ways (hiding the calendars, reprinting the headers, other ways).

Here is the base setup:  http://jsfiddle.net/jzqJC/.  I am looking for some direction in how to have the main content area have (1) both vertical and horizontal scrollbars as necessary, (2) keep the column headers fixed when vertical scrolling, and (3) synchronize the horizontal scrolling of the column headers and calendars underneath them.  I have spent several days tinkering and trying things based on stackoverflow and google searches, but I am at a loss and need help.  Please advise.

[Side question:  how can I link to fullcalendar.min.js in a fiddle?  Do I need a public URL for the file and add it as a resource?  If so, what's the best way to put out that file in a public URL?]

Thanks,
J

Comment: This is not a solution to your question - but have you seen a plugin called jQuery-Layout? http://layout.jquery-dev.net/ - might help you achieve this.

Comment: That's pretty cool, but it seems like it only helps with the header, footer, and sidebar.  I can't find a way to make it solve the scrolling issue.

Comment: You could add a script including it in the html like this: <script src="http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize he had one public out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this Fiddle, take a look if it is what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/7NgUB/

I changed .headerItem,.calendarItem display to inline and #headerRow,#calendarRow position to absolute in the CSS.

Then everything is done with jquery:

Asign #headerRow,#calendarRow width the total width of its children, 
Set #calendarRow top position to appear below #headerRow,
Change #headerRow top position each time #content is scrolled

Comment: This works great in the fiddle, but I can't get it to work in my project.  I'm trying to cut things out until it works.  I updated the fiddle to use fullcalendar.js per Alvaro's comment:  http://jsfiddle.net/RJvhk/.

Question:  what is the 'lleft' variable used for?  I don't see where it's being used.

Comment: It is not used for anything, I just tried several things and forgot to erase it. Your fiddle looks good to me, whats the problem?

Comment: I think ultimately it was a version problem, when I pointed to a clean 1.5.3 fullcalendar.min.js file, it works!
Next problem:  the header is behind the fullcalendar objects when you scroll downwards.  See this fiddle with .calendar{background-color:Green;}:  http://jsfiddle.net/S9DKV/.  Set background color to transparent, and you can see the headers when you scroll downward.  I tried setting the z-index of the headers to 9999, but that didn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Also, I would upvote your answer because it's *extremely* helpful, but I lack the reputation.  Just want to say thanks for helping out.

Comment: Tha one is easy, just add this properties to #calendarHeaderRow z-index:100; background-color:white; http://jsfiddle.net/Ukywv/2/ .Glad it helped, so you can't give the answer a right?

Comment: Awesome!  I actually got it to work with z-index as low as 5.

Comment: Oh I am *definitely* marking this as the answer, I just want to also upvote it since it's extremely awesome.

Comment: Approving your answer gave me the last rep points I needed to have upvote privileges, so I upvoted your excellent answer.  I also added a short delay and animation to the scrolling to keep it from being so choppy:  http://jsfiddle.net/Vvy5P/.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your upvote! I am glad everything went ok' looks great with the delay.